# All possible combinations in data set with nested groups that are ordered sequencially in R

Tags: r

I posted this question earlier, but after a few comments I realized a better explanation of the `df` and `result` are needed. Additionally, I realized a simplified data structure can be used to achieve my goals.

I need to find all combinations of values within a specific sequence.

In the example `df` you can see the nested grouping structure, with `GROUP` nested within `SAMPLE` and `SITE`. My actual data set has ~1000 `SAMPLE` across 30 `SITE`.  Note that each `GROUP` is in sequence (1 to 3) and this sequence needs to be retained in the final result as this is a critical part of future analyses.  In other words, combinations that put `GROUP` 2 or 3 before `GROUP` 1 are not needed.

Within each `GROUP` are 2 or 3 text or numeric values in the `ASSIGN_1`, `ASSIGN_2`, and `ASSIGN_3` columns. For example, F1 has 3 groups and each group has 2 possibilities: `GROUP` 1 has 4 and unk_palmer_trib; `GROUP` 2 has 6.1 and 5.2; and ‘GROUP’ 3 has 10.1 and 6.1. You can see `SAMPLE` B2 also has three groups, with `GROUP` 1 and 3 having two possibilities and `GROUP` 2 having three possibilities.

So…I need to find all the possible combinations of the values in the `ASSIGN` columns while retaining the sequence of the `GROUP`. Note that `OPTION` columns in the `result` are the various combinations of values from the `ASSIGN` columns in the `df` and you will notice that these combinations retain the `GROUP` sequence (i.e., 1 to 3).  Also note that the number of `OPTION` columns with data (i.e., no “NAs”) in the `result` correspond to all the possible combinations of the `ASSIGN` columns that retain the `GROUP` sequence. `SAMPLE` F1 has 3 groups each with 2 possibilities and thus there are 8 possible outcomes (i.e., 2 x 2 x 2; see `OPTION` columns 1 to 8). `SAMPLE` B2 has 3 groups (2 groups with two possibilities and 1 group with three possibilities) and thus there are 12 possible outcomes (i.e., 2 x 3 x 2; see `OPTION` columns 1 to 12).

To really push this point home, lets look at `SAMPLE` F1 in the `df` and the `result` to illustrate how these combinations need to be structured. `OPTION_1` for F1 is just the `ASSIGN_1` column from `df`. `OPTION_2` is row 1 from `ASSIGN_1` (i.e., GROUP_1 = 4) and then rows 2 and 3 from ASSIGN_2 (i.e., GROUP_2 = 5.2 and GROUP_3 = 6.1). ‘OPTION_3’ is row 1 from `ASSIGN_1` (i.e., GROUP_1 = 4), row 2 from `ASSIGN_2` (i.e., GROUP_2 = 5.2) and row 3 from `ASSIGN_1` (i.e., GROUP_3 = 10.1). Repeat at nauseum….

In my actual data set, some of the `GROUP` can have up to 5 `ASSIGN` columns…so the number of possible combinations can be large for some `SAMPLE`.

I have tried using `expand.grid()` within `ave()`, but have not been able to get the code to work. I am open to all solutions, but prefer `base package` solutions as I want to avoid having to load packages. I also suspect that the `df` likely needs to be restructured in some way…which is perfectly fine so long as the `GROUP` sequence is retained in the final product.

Let me know if I need to clarify.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
df <- read.table(text = "SITE   SAMPLE  GROUP   ASSIGN_1    ASSIGN_2    ASSIGN_3
A1  F1  1   4   unk_palmer_trib NA
A1  F1  2   6.1 5.2 NA
A1  F1  3   10.1    6.1 NA
M15 B2  1   6.2 6.4 NA
M15 B2  2   10.1    6.1 5.2
M15 B2  3   10.1    6.1 NA
", header = TRUE)

result <- read.table(text = "SITE   SAMPLE  GROUP   OPTION_1    OPTION_2    OPTION_3    OPTION_4    OPTION_5    OPTION_6    OPTION_7    OPTION_8    OPTION_9    OPTION_10   OPTION_11   OPTION_12
A1  F1  1   4   4   4   4   unk_palmer_trib unk_palmer_trib unk_palmer_trib unk_palmer_trib NA  NA  NA  NA
A1  F1  2   6.1 5.2 5.2 6.1 6.1 5.2 5.2 6.1 NA  NA  NA  NA
A1  F1  3   10.1    6.1 10.1    6.1 10.1    6.1 10.1    6.1 NA  NA  NA  NA
M15 B2  1   6.2 6.2 6.2 6.2 6.2 6.2 6.4 6.4 6.4 6.4 6.4 6.4
M15 B2  2   10.1    6.1 10.1    6.1 5.2 5.2 10.1    6.1 10.1    6.1 5.2 5.2
M15 B2  3   10.1    6.1 6.1 10.1    10.1    6.1 10.1    6.1 6.1 10.1    10.1    6.1
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a stab :-)

```r
func <- function(x, keep = integer(0)) {
  if (length(keep)) {
    saved <- x[,keep,drop=FALSE]
    x <- x[,-keep]
  } else {
    saved <- x[,0] # empty column
  }
  out <- t(do.call(expand.grid, asplit(t(x), 2)))
  out <- as.data.frame(out[, colSums(is.na(out)) == 0])
  colnames(out) <- paste0("OPTION_", seq_along(out))
  cbind(saved, out)
}
```

The `keep=` argument is an integer vector of the fields that need to be preserved and *not* expanded in the combinations.

Demonstration:

```r
LOF <- Filter(length, by(df, df[,c("SITE","SAMPLE")], FUN = func, keep = 1:3))
allnames <- unique(unlist(lapply(LOF, colnames)))
LOF <- lapply(LOF, function(z) { z[setdiff(allnames, colnames(z))] <- NA; z; })
do.call(rbind, LOF)
#   SITE SAMPLE GROUP OPTION_1        OPTION_2 OPTION_3        OPTION_4 OPTION_5        OPTION_6 OPTION_7        OPTION_8 OPTION_9 OPTION_10 OPTION_11 OPTION_12
# 4  M15     B2     1      6.2             6.4      6.2             6.4      6.2             6.4      6.2             6.4      6.2       6.4       6.2       6.4
# 5  M15     B2     2     10.1            10.1      6.1             6.1      5.2             5.2     10.1            10.1      6.1       6.1       5.2       5.2
# 6  M15     B2     3     10.1            10.1     10.1            10.1     10.1            10.1      6.1             6.1      6.1       6.1       6.1       6.1
# 1   A1     F1     1      4.0 unk_palmer_trib      4.0 unk_palmer_trib      4.0 unk_palmer_trib      4.0 unk_palmer_trib     <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
# 2   A1     F1     2      6.1             6.1      5.2             5.2      6.1             6.1      5.2             5.2     <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
# 3   A1     F1     3     10.1            10.1     10.1            10.1      6.1             6.1      6.1             6.1     <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
```

If you are already using `data.table`, then this can be simplified to the first plus either of the second or third:

```r
LOF <- Filter(length, by(df, df[,c("SITE","SAMPLE")], FUN = func, keep = 1:3))
data.table::rbindlist(LOF, fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
dplyr::bind_rows(LOF)
```

Comment: The code works great! Thanks legend. Take care.